# Split specific part of JSON file and export it

Tags: json, excel, vba

I have JSON file and this is a preview of its structure
[image]

Is there a way to cut off the 'allTests' part and export it to new JSON file?

Comment: Please can you provide the JSON string.

Comment: If too much to post above can you post a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)  link?

Comment: Here's a link of JSON file
[link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/e7gjyyb9ad1phzy/Sample.zip/file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. Special characters are preserved. Hopefully the relevant JSON is *cut* out.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetJSONExtract()
    Dim fso As Object, jsonFile As Object, jsonText As String, arr() As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set jsonFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sample.json")
    jsonText = jsonFile.ReadAll
    arr = Split(jsonText, Chr$(34) & "allTests" & Chr$(34))
    jsonText = Replace$(arr(2), ":", vbNullString, 1, 1)
    jsonText = Split(jsonText, Chr$(34) & "time" & Chr$(34))(0)
    jsonText = Left$(jsonText, InStrRev(jsonText, ",") - 1)
    With fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test.json")
        .write jsonText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. If you opened JSON file with notepad++ and searched for 'allTests' you will find two occurrences .. I mean the second one which locates at Line 1240

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have fixed this line `fs.WriteText JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)("results")(1)("allTests"))`

Comment: I am confused .. there is data but the JSON is invalid

Comment: I tried UTF-16 and the same. Is there a way to check if the JSON file is valid or not?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It throws an error 'Invalid procedure call or argument' at the line of fs.WriteText

Comment: Can you try again?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working well as for extracting
I have noticed that the string 'Sonetàula' which is in the original file doesn't appear correctly in the output file. I tried using utf-16 and the same problem.. Any idea?

Comment: It is lilkely a UTF problem on the way in or out. Do you lose the à?

Comment: Yes I lost this letter à and there may be other loses :)
I think Tim's code is fine but I don't know why it is invalid ...!!

By the way why I got -1 for my main post ?

Comment: Tim is doing what I did first. I had the same problem remember. I can't answer as to why you got minus 1 except that perhaps it is because you showed no code. But that said, I have  seen anwers with no code gets lots of upvotes/downvotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your existing code is perfect as it is valid JSON. But its problem is with the lost of some letters and this worries me

Comment: Try the latest version.

Comment: You're amazing. That's perfect now. Thank you very very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181857/discussion-between-qharr-and-yasserkhalil).

Answer (score 2):

Using:  https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

```
Sub ParseItOut()

    Const f_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\"
    Dim fso, j, obj, subObj
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    j = fso.OpenTextFile(f_PATH & "sample.json").ReadAll()

    Set obj = JsonConverter.ParseJson(j)

    'get the required section
    Set subObj = obj("results")(1)("allTests")

    'write to file as JSON 
    fso.CreateTextFile(f_PATH & "sample_mod.json").Write JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(subObj)

End Sub
```

EDIT: this seems to be a problem -

[image]

Under allTests each item is an object with a single property/key (which is very large and contains embedded quotes escaped by `\`) and a value of `true`

The library I used seems to have an issue with that (or I don't know how to use it correctly...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It results to invalid JSON and I can't recognize why
You can copy and paste to this link to validate the output [link](https://jsonformatter.org/)

Comment: There are notes about the error in the link I provided in my previous comment

Comment: This is the same problem I had with ConvertToJson. Interested in why this is the case. + for keeping the special characters.

Comment: The issue is the embedded/escaped quotes in the keys for `allTests` - I'm not sure what the fix would be for that.

Comment: @Tim: What do you mean by 'escaped quotes' ..? And is it difficult to deal with it?
I appreciate if you put snapshot illustrating the 'escaped quotes' .. and how this affects the output?